# When to use the table operator APPLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cross-apply, sql

I'm trying to understand the table operator `APPLY`.

Here is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE #y ( Name char(8), hoursWorked int);
GO
INSERT INTO #y VALUES ('jim',4);
INSERT INTO #y VALUES ('michael',40);
INSERT INTO #y VALUES ('raj',1000);
INSERT INTO #y VALUES ('jason',7);
INSERT INTO #y VALUES ('tim',50);
GO

CREATE TABLE #x ( Name char(8),game char(8), NumBets int);
GO
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('jim','chess',4);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('jim','BG',10);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('jim','draughts',100);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('jim','football',5);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('michael','chess',40);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('michael','BG',7);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('michael','draughts',65);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('michael','football',50);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('raj','chess',400);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('raj','BG',70);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('raj','draughts',650);
INSERT INTO #x VALUES ('tim','draughts',60000);
GO

SELECT  y.Name, 
        y.hoursWorked,
        x.game,
        x.NumBets
FROM    #y y
        OUTER APPLY 
          (
          SELECT TOP 2 *
          FROM   #x
          WHERE  Name = y.Name 
          ORDER BY NumBets
        ) x
ORDER BY  y.Name,
        x.NumBets DESC;
```

My main hurdle is understanding *when* to use `APPLY`.
So I'm wondering how difficult would it be to get the same result as above using `standard sql` implemented in `sql-server 2005` ?
Does `APPLY` make the query a lot shorter or more readable?
If this example shows no massive advantages to using `APPLY` then what is a clear example where there is an advantage to using `APPLY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - with `apply` you could call **table-valued functions** where parameter values are taken from table you query, something like this:

```
select
    t1.col3, -- column from table
    f1.col1  -- column from function
from table1 as t1
    left outer join table2 as t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1
    outer apply dbo.function1(t1.col1, t2.col2) as f1
```

or **shredding xml columns**

```
select
    t1.col3,
    t.c.value('@value', 'int') as value
from table1 as t1
    -- table1.col1 is xml iike <Data @Value="...">...</Data>
    outer apply t1.col1.nodes('Data') as t(c)
```

From my expirience, `apply` is very useful when you have to make some **precalculation**:

```
select
    t1.col3,
    a1.col1,  --calculated value
    a2.col1   -- another calculated value, first one was used
from table1 as t1
    outer apply (select t1.col1 * 5 as col1) as a1
    outer apply (select a1.col1 - 4 as col1) as a2
```

another example of using `apply` is **unpivot** operation:

```
select
    t1.col1, c.name, c.value
from table1 as t1
    outer apply (
        select 'col1', t1.col1 union all
        select 'col2', t1.col2
    ) as c(name, value)
```

finally, here's **your query** implemented in terms of SQL 2005 without using **apply**:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        y.Name, 
        y.hoursWorked,
        x.game,
        x.NumBets,
        row_number() over(partition by x.Name order by x.NumBets) as row_num
    from y
        left outer join x on x.Name = y.Name
)
select Name, hoursWorked, game, NumBets
from cte
where row_num <= 2
order by Name, NumBets desc
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29055/5) example

Comment: +1 very nice extensive answer - not had time to fully absorb this yet

Comment: I think `APPLY` is shorter than the 2005 version. Not too sure if I'd ever use the `UNPIVOT` version - its a nice trick but as the specific `UNPIVOT` function shipped with the same version of sql-server why not just use that. Seems like, for me, the best applications will be its interaction with the TVF and also the correlated use of apply for calculations.

Comment: I think that Apply could be faster than row_number, but not sure about this, have to test later