# Addition and Division

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed help with doing division calculations with one decimal. I am trying to sum and divide the result. My Y and X are integers.

```
SELECT a.YearMonth,
       (CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1),Y_Service)+(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1),x_Service)/2)) AS Average_Of_Period
FROM table_IB a
  INNER JOIN table_UB b ON a.YearMonth=b.YearMonth
```

This is the result I get:

```
YearMonth|  Average_Of_Period         
  2015-03    276318.500000
```

The correct answer is :`185532,5`

My Y and X values differ from 4 digits to 6 digits

Comment: First to the calculation, then cast/convert the result.

Comment: is your /2 in the correct place? It looks like it needs to move out a bracket or two. y + (x/2) should be (y+x)/2

Comment: What are the values of X and Y for which the correct answer is 185532,5?

Comment: My Y is 181572 and my X is 189493. So (Y+X)/2=185532,5 in the calculator. With my corrected code:(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1),Y_Service)+(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1),X_Service)))/2 AS  Average_Of_Period I get this result:"185532.500000". What should I write so it only shows:185532.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your operation is (y) + (x / 2)?

Should that be ( y + x ) / 2?

Answer (score 0):

Readability matters. In case you have to do some ugly casts before calculation, you can always do it with common table expression or [outer apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126961/1744834):

```
select
    a.YearMonth,
    (calc.Y_Service + calc.x_Service) / 2 as Average_Of_Period
from table_IB as a
    inner join table_UB as b on a.YearMonth = b.YearMonth 
    outer apply (select
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1), Y_Service) as Y_Service,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1), x_Service) as x_Service
    ) as calc
```

And then you'd not miss that you're doing `Y_Service + x_Service / 2` instead of `(Y_Service + x_Service) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead; it's easier:

```
select (x + y)/2.0
```

Adding the decimal point to the 2 will change the result from integer division to standard division.  This will also work, for the same reason:

```
select (x + y)*1.0/2
```

If you want to explicitly convert decimals, easiest to add first - as other commenters have mentioned this will make it easier to spot mathematical errors:

```
select cast(x + y as decimal(10,2))/2
```